# set a UIButton to call a certain number Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an app with 4 UIButtons and I want to pre-program phone numbers to each of them. I have written it like this:

```
- (IBAction)callFirst:(id)sender {
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel.0739421700"];
}

- (IBAction)callSecond:(id)sender {
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel.0705652000"];
}

- (IBAction)callThird:(id)sender {
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel.0705666900"];
}

- (IBAction)callFourth:(id)sender {
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel.0702857900"];
}
```

When I just open the app on the simulator it takes me to the log and shows errors. How should I write it instead?
This is what comes up when I run it. The "return UIApplicationMain... " part is marked with green arrows on its edges. On the right it says " Thread 1: signal sigabrt" Its from the main.m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: your code is wrong but it will not crash. check the connections in your xib or storyboard

Comment: cant it be as Matthias Bauch said I have to call the URL?

Comment: the buttons wasn't connected but it doesn't work anyway:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't [open the url](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14)
2. you used the wrong [url scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)

something like this should work:

```
- (BOOL)callPhoneNumberWithString:(NSString *)phoneNumberString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberString];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)callFirst:(id)sender {
    [self callPhoneNumberWithString:@"tel:0123456789"]; 
}
```

Comment: It shows the same thing as before:( but how should I repeat this for the other actions?